# getting value to text feild using knockout.js in php

Tags: knockout.js

Getting a value to a text box from another text box using `knockout.js` in laravel 5.

```
var viewModel = {
    theValue: ko.observable("hghgu"),
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

This code is not working. Please help me with this, I am new in `knockout.js`.

Comment: this code will work. I think it is due to some other issue, can you please post more code. or create a fiddle

Comment: please check the code :::  https://jsfiddle.net/yv6vwcLq/

Comment: you for got to include knockout library, lol

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yv6vwcLq/3/ updated

Comment: Also, prefer the simpler `textInput: partial` instead of `value: partial, valueUpdate: 'afterKeyDown'`

Answer (score 0):

Just use the 'input' option on valueUpdate parameter instead of 'afterKeyDown' option.

HTML:

```
<input data-bind="value: partial, valueUpdate: 'input'" /> 
<input data-bind="value: partial, valueUpdate: 'input'" />
```

Javascript:

```
var viewModel = {
partial: ko.observable("hello world"),
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```